# StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync() method with a search pattern?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, storagefile

In the regular .NET Framework, there are a number of methods for retrieving a subset of files in a directory based on a search pattern, for example [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(string searchPattern)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx).

Is there a corresponding method for Windows Store applications? *.NET for Windows Store apps* does not contain the `Directory` or `DirectoryInfo` classes, and neither of the [StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfilesasync.aspx) overloads in the *Windows API* support search patterns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Windows.Storage.Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR208106) namespace allows you to do file searches with patterns. Also, the [Programmatic file search sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Programmatically-searching-25e1a56b/sourcecode?fileId=43715&pathId=589460989) from Microsoft demonstrates how to use the api.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently the search patterns can be made very complex using the Advanced Query Syntax, but it is not obvious to me if I can also apply the "classic" file search patterns like `*hello*`, `?alid_name*.*` etc. in AQS. Are you able to expand on the subject?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson - Take a look at the `SearchButton_Click` function in the search sample in the Scenario1.xaml.cs file in the second link above. They use a `*` pattern in the search. I am not sure if `?` is supported, although it would be easy to find out.

Comment: Yes, they use the `*` pattern for the `FileTypeFilter`, but there is no explicit example of the `UserSearchFilter` (not in XAML nor in the code-behind file), which is primarily what I am aiming for.

Comment: I have made some initial tests, and it actually seems like `*` filtering is working OK, which should be enough for now. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: Just a note to UWP developers today: Wildcards do not seem to be supported in UWP.